# Storing session in href

Tags: php, html, session-variables

I want to store some data into a session so I can transfer it between pages. I will have a lot of images present and need an efficient way of storing data. So I've done

`<a href="create2.php?" ><?php?$_SESSION["choice_1"]=2;?><img src="pictures/laptops/reebok.png" height="150"></td></a>;`

However the when I call the session in another page, it says it is undefined. I could do it this way or when the image is clicked, I could store some data into a variable, call a function, save the variable into the session and then load the new page. However I do not know how I could do this. Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to store a session variable for each of the images, or you want to store a session variable for the images that are clicked? If you want the second, you should use Ajax, or use Javascript and cookies instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st, your html is broken, there's a `</td>` that should not be there.

About your question, you don't have to pass the value in the URL (which is not done that way however), you only need the session id if you don't want to use cookies, and use it to start the session.
Your link:

```
<a href="create2.php?<?php echo session_name().'='.session_id(); ?>">
    <img src="pictures/laptops/reebok.png" alt="reebok" height="150">
</a>
```

In create2.php call `session_start()` before everything. Of course you don't need to pass the session id in the URL if you use cookies.

Comment: I've done `<a href="create2.php?<?php echo session_name($_SESSION["choice_1"]).'='.session_id("2"); ?>">` I've done that but it doesnt seem to be working. I call `session_start()` on both pages but it still says undefined on the second page. I could turn to an easier method if there is one?

Comment: Why are you writing `$_SESSION["choice_1"]` and `"2"` there? Copy paste the html I wrote, in the calling php make sure you put `$_SESSION["choice_1"] = 2;` and in create2.php you should be able to do `echo $_SESSION["choice_1"];`. Of course you need `session_start();` in both pages. To simplify that, just use cookies and forget about passing the session id in the URL.

Comment: Maybe you don't really want to use a SESSION variable, but just to pass a value via URL? Try this: `<a href="create2.php?choice_1=2"><img src="pictures/laptops/reebok.png" alt="reebok" height="150"></a>`. In create2.php then use `<?php if (isset($_GET['choice_1'])) echo $_GET['choice_1']; ?>`

Comment: Thank you, I'll just use the URL to pass the value

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're calling `session_start()` at the top of each of your PHP files before you try to access/modify session variables.

Comment: Before `anything` is written to the document, including whitespace and newlines.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your php init tag is wrong `<?php?` should be `<?php`. Second, you should be initializing the session in your php:

```
<?php
// nothing before here, session_start must be the very first thing on the page
session_start();
```

And finally, you're not creating any php link that way, you are only defining the variable but it has nothing to do wint the `a` tag.

To send the 'choice_1' which is stored in the SESSION global variable trough URL you should do:

```
<a href="create2.php?choice_1=<?=$_SESSION['choice_1']?>">
  <img src="pictures/laptops/reebok.png" height="150">
</a>;
```

Comment: You can call `session_start()` after some other PHP code, you just can't output anything on the document beforehand.